# Create Self signed CA certificate and install in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, ssl

I have created WCF Service with username/password & certificate authentication. It works fine from visual studio.

Now,I would like to host the WCF service on IIS(development server)
Server: Windows Server Standard without Hyper-V (Service pack 2)
IIS: 7

Can someone show me the way to create self signed certificate on server and assign it to IIS for the WCF service(Chain Trust Certificate). And how can I generate the key certificate for the clients to consume service.

Thank You

Comment: Check out the following link for detailed steps: http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/

Comment: Here are quick steps to generate the self signed certificate from IIS itself. http://www.cshandler.com/2015/10/setting-up-ssl-encryption-to-wcf-rest.html

Answer (score 1):

Bear with me if the procedure is quite long but this procedure helped me to create self-sign CA during our development.

**Steps on how to create self-signed certificate:**

Assumptions:

- Visual Studio was already installed (2012/2013/2015).
- You have already basic knowlegdge of digital certificate (x.509).

Steps:

- Open Visual Studio Tools and choose Developer Command Prompt for
  VS2013/VS2012 as an administrator. And navigate or cd to location
  where you want to save your certificates.
- We need to create first Root Authority as our CA for signing
  certificate. To create Root Authority certificate, we used
  makecert.exe tool that comes from visual studio. For more detail
  regarding makecert.exe please refer here.

  ```
  Command: makecert –n “CN=DevRootCA” –r –sv DevRootCA.pvk DevRootCA.cer
  ```
- Explanation: The command above will generate a root authority
  certificate for signing certificate.
     Create self-signed certificate using our Root Authority certificate came from Step 2.

  ```
  Command: makecert –pe –n “CN= localhost” –ss my –sky exchange –sk DevCert –iv DevRootCA.pvk –ic DevRootCA.cer –sr localmachine DevCert.cer
  Explanation: The command above will create and store certificate named “DevCert.cer” and it will be stored in Local Computer. To view certificates stored in your local computer Use Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe). Please refer here
  ```
- In able for the server and client to trust each certificate named
  “DevCert.cer” you need to install Root Authority certificate in
  client and server.

  ```
  Open Microsoft Management Console and follow here.
  Navigate to Certificate (Local Computer)
  Trusted Root Certification Authority
  Certificates
  At right side of panel right click at empty space All Task
  Import certificate then locate your Root Authority certificate.
  ```
- Export self-signed certificate named “DevCert.cer” with private key
  for your client.

  ```
  Use MMC again for this step and navigate to
  Certificate (Local Computer)
  Trusted Root Certification Authority
  Certificates
  At the right side of panel right click the certificate that you want to export
  All tasks
  Export (Press Next)
  Choose option Yes
  Export the private key
  Leave default option (Press Next)
  Enter password (Press Next). Note : The password must much to the previouse password you enter upon creation.
  Browse where you want to save
  Next and Finish
  ```
- Use exported certificate and install to your client machine.

**How to install self-sign certificate in IIS:**

Assumptions:

- You have already the certificate installed in your client machine or server.
- How to install self-sign certificate using [MMC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754431.aspx).

Steps :

- Open IIS manager and click local host that correspond to your machine
  right after start page.
- Click Default Web Site.
- At the right side of the Actions Pane click Bindings.
- Click Add and choose Type: https and OK button. (if https already
  exists just change the certificate )
- And choose SSL Certificate that correspond to you certificate. Then,
  Click OK and close.
- To verify if your website is already using the certificate you setup.
  Go to your browse and navigate to your site and see if it prompt you
  about the certificate or if the site has padlock beside the URL.
  Click the padlock and see if it is your certificate.

**Important:** This procedure is for development cycle only and not for production. For production you need to acquire SSL certificate from Certificate Authority.